# Facing a problem with Reinforcement learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

```
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import A2C

env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2', render_mode="human")  
env.reset()

model = A2C("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)

episodes = 10

for ep in range(episodes):
    obs = env.reset()
    done = False
    while not done:
        action, _states, _episode, _determ = model.predict(obs)
        obs, rewards, done, info = env.step(action)
        env.render()

env.close()
```

My code above produces this output:

```
DeprecationWarning: `np.bool8` is a deprecated alias for `np.bool_`.  (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)
  if not isinstance(terminated, (bool, np.bool8)):
------------------------------------
| rollout/              |          |
|    ep_len_mean        | 89.2     |
|    ep_rew_mean        | -227     |
| time/                 |          |
|    fps                | 43       |
|    iterations         | 100      |
|    time_elapsed       | 11       |
|    total_timesteps    | 500      |
| train/                |          |
|    entropy_loss       | -1.29    |
|    explained_variance | -0.0216  |
|    learning_rate      | 0.0007   |
|    n_updates          | 99       |
|    policy_loss        | 2.79     |
|    value_loss         | 12.3     |
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
| rollout/              |          |
|    ep_len_mean        | 107      |
|    ep_rew_mean        | -209     |
| time/                 |          |
|    fps                | 45       |
|    iterations         | 200      |
|    time_elapsed       | 21       |
|    total_timesteps    | 1000     |
| train/                |          |
|    entropy_loss       | -0.864   |
|    explained_variance | -0.00161 |
|    learning_rate      | 0.0007   |
|    n_updates          | 199      |
|    policy_loss        | -16.6    |
|    value_loss         | 228      |
```

followed by this error:

```
------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Appu\Courses\Fun projects\Reinforcement Learning\c1.py", line 17, in <module>
    action, _states, _episode, _determ = model.predict(obs)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sarav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\base_class.py", line 555, in predict
    return self.policy.predict(observation, state, episode_start, deterministic)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sarav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\policies.py", line 346, in predict
    observation, vectorized_env = self.obs_to_tensor(observation)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sarav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\policies.py", line 260, in obs_to_tensor
    observation = np.array(observation)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

When i run the code it runs a few timesteps and exits with the error above. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by the changes of API in new versions of the gym. Please see solutions in [Solutions for changes API in the new gym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238133/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-in-python-openai-gym/77833181#77833181)

For example, you can downgrade `gym` to a compatible old version, like `gym==0.18.0`; Or you can change your code by reviewing only the required parameters you want, and passing the correct parameters to `numpy`. For example,

```
obs,_ = env.reset()
```

You may need to adapt code for the similar API `predict(), step()` of `gym` as well.

Please refer to the gym's API website https://www.gymlibrary.dev/api/core/ for more details about the changes in new gym versions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35534756)