# ValueError: Setting an array element with a sequence in Python OpenAI Gym

Tags: python, openai-gym

I'm working on implementing a Q-learning algorithm using OpenAI Gym's MountainCar-v0 environment. However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
discrete_state = (state - env.observation_space.low) / discrete_os_win_size
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimension. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Can someone please help me understand what's causing this error and how to fix it?

Code:

```
import gym
import numpy as np
env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0", render_mode='human')
env.reset()

LEARNING_RATE = 0.1
DISCOUNT = 0.95
EPISODES = 25000
SHOW_EVERY = 2000
DISCRETE_OS_SIZE = [20] * len(env.observation_space.high)
discrete_os_win_size = (env.observation_space.high - env.observation_space.low) / np.array(DISCRETE_OS_SIZE)
q_table = np.random.uniform(low=-2, high=0, size=(DISCRETE_OS_SIZE + [env.action_space.n]))

def get_discrete_state(state):
    print('this is the state:', state)
    discrete_state = (state - env.observation_space.low) / discrete_os_win_size
    return tuple(discrete_state.astype(np.int))

for episode in range(EPISODES):
    if episode % SHOW_EVERY == 0:
        print(episode)
        render = True
    else:
        render = False

    discrete_state = get_discrete_state(env.reset())

    done = False
    while not done:
        action = np.argmax(q_table[discrete_state])

        new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)[:4]

        new_discrete_state = get_discrete_state(new_state)

        if render:
            env.render()

        if not done:
            max_future_q = np.max(q_table[new_discrete_state])
            current_q = q_table[discrete_state][action]
            new_q = (1 - LEARNING_RATE) * current_q + LEARNING_RATE * (reward + DISCOUNT * max_future_q)
            q_table[discrete_state][action] = new_q
        elif new_state[0] >= env.goal_position:
            q_table[discrete_state][action] = 0 
        discrete_state = new_discrete_state

env.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error

```
Setting an array element with a sequence ...
```

when using `gym` with the following code, in my case:

```
gym.spaces.flatten(self.observation_space,state).reshape(1,-1)

gym.spaces.flatten(self.observation_space,state).reshape(1,-1),reward,done,info
```

The problem may be because the new version of `gym==0.26.1` gives more output than expected, which results in more parameters being passed to `numpy`. After I upgraded my environment, I installed a new version of `gym==0.26.1`, and this problem occurred. Before that, I was using `gym==0.18.0` and met no error.

Here are my solutions:

(1) Downgrade `gym` to a compatible old version, for example in my case 0.18.0, with

```
pip install gym==0.18.0
```

OR another solution:

(2) Modify the code while using the new version `gym==0.26.1` (or maybe higher). For example, in your case, the following code may help:

```
s, _ = env.reset()
discrete_state = get_discrete_state(s)

new_state, reward, done, _, _ = env.step(action)[:4]
```

Please refer to the gym's API website `https://www.gymlibrary.dev/api/core/` for more details about the changes in new gym versions.

Best